# Pinia : state change by It self

Tags: javascript, date, vuejs3, getter, pinia

G'day,

I would like to have 3 elements :

- Current Date  (to display current month)
- current date less 1 month  (to display the month before)
- current date plus 1 month  (to display the next month)

I calculate the 2 others months in getter, but when I calc my "lastmonth", it change the selectedMonth value in getter environment :

my code :

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import type {
  agendaState,
} from "@/myApp/interfaces";

export const useAgenda = defineStore("useAgenda", {
  state: (): agendaState => ({
    selectedMonth: new Date(),
    lastMonth: new Date(),
    nextMonth: new Date(),
  }),
  getters: {
    lastMonthCalc: (state: agendaState): Date => {
      console.log("selectedMonth before : ", state.selectedMonth);
      const myDate = state.selectedMonth;
      state.lastMonth = myDate;
      state.lastMonth = new Date(
        state.lastMonth.setMonth(state.lastMonth.getMonth() - 1)
        );
        console.log("lastMonth after : ", state.lastMonth);
        return state.lastMonth;
      },
      nextMonthCalc: (state: agendaState): Date => {
      console.log("selectedMonth before : ", state.selectedMonth);
      const theDate = state.selectedMonth;
      state.nextMonth = theDate;
      state.nextMonth = new Date(
        state.nextMonth.setMonth(state.nextMonth.getMonth() + 1)
      );
      console.log("nextMonth after : ", state.nextMonth);
      return state.nextMonth;
    },
  },
});
```

The VueJS plugin in chrome display :
[image]

My console log looks like (in the chrome console)  :
[image]

And I would like to have :

selectedMonth =  Thu Feb 09 2023 11:05:41 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale),

lastMonth: Mon Jan 09 2023 11:05:41 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale),

nextMonth: Thu Mar 09 2023 11:05:41 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale),

Do you know why ? What is my mistake ?

I try a lot of things but nothing workss.

Comment: Yes, myDate and state.selectedMonth are both reference variables, and so if one is assigned to the other, changing the state of one will of necessity change the state of the other. This is not really a Vue or Pinia-specific issue but rather is a basic JavaScript issue.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution .... the good code is this one :

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import type {
  agendaState,
} from "@/interfaces";

export const useAgenda = defineStore("useAgenda", {
  state: (): agendaState => ({
    selectedMonth: new Date(),
  }),
  getters: {
    lastMonth: (state: agendaState): Date => {
     const myDate = new Date(state.selectedMonth);
      new Date(
        myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() - 1)
        );
        return myDate;
      },
      nextMonth: (state: agendaState): Date => {
      const theDate = new Date(state.selectedMonth);
       new Date(
        theDate.setMonth(theDate.getMonth() + 1)
      );
      return theDate;
    },
  },
});
```

Thanks to my cat to show me what is the point so I change the code for this last version !!!!